# Power Apps without internet connection

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, sql, offline

I am wondering is it possible to create a PowerApp mobile app which can function without internet connection and perhaps store data from the database (i.e SharePoint List or SQL Database) locally on the device in case the app needs to be used offline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to develop offline-capable canvas apps.

Here is what you can do:

- Determine when an app is offline, online, or in a metered connection by using the [Connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/signals#connection) signal object.
- Use collections and leverage the [LoadData and SaveData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-savedata-loaddata) functions for basic data storage when offline.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Develop offline-capable canvas apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/offline-apps)

**Additional References**:

1. [Build offline apps with new PowerApps capabilities](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-offline-apps-with-new-powerapps-capabilities/)
2. [Implementing Offline Capability In Your App](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/implementing-offline-capability-in-your-app/)

There are some limitations with using offline capabilities. You can check it in documentation and references given above.

Comment: Thank you for the input and references they were extremely useful. I still have a few questions. Say the app is an app which collects user input through a form. What if the user submits multiple forms while in offline mode ?  Will the app submit the form in sequence or randomly?  And how will the app store this local cache which is stored on the device ?  If you have any information about this I would be extremely grateful

Comment: As per the documentation (link given above), this operate on an in-memory collection. Available memory can vary depending on the device, the operating system, the memory that Power Apps Mobile uses, and the complexity of the app in terms of screens and controls. If you store more than a few megabytes of data, test your app with expected scenarios on the devices on which you expect it to run. You'll generally have 30-70 megabytes of available memory.

Comment: About submitting multiple forms, this is up to you and how you design your app. when user comes online you will load data from local memory in a collection and then you can submit the data to data source as per your requirements.